# How to add NSArray in a video with AVMutableMetadataItem?

Tags: objective-c, video, nsarray, metadata, avmetadataitem

I am trying to save video with custom NSArray metadata relevant for my app and trying to retrieve it when the user selects that video from the library. 
I'm using the AVAssetExportSession function to add metadata.

I used the sample code AVMovieExporter, and I tried to change locationMetadata.value 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVMovieExporter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011364

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *locationMetadata = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
locationMetadata.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyLocation;
locationMetadata.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
locationMetadata.locale = self.locale;
//locationMetadata.value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+08.4lf%+09.4lf", self.location.coordinate.latitude, self.location.coordinate.longitude];

locationMetadata.value = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"abc", @123,nil];
```

If I use value as a NSString there is no problem, but if I use a NSArray, it doesn't save the metadata.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation [states](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationMetadataKeyReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Common_Metadata_Keys):

```
NSString *const AVMetadataCommonKeyLocation;
```

I understand that to say the value must be a string, and cannot be an array.

Comment: It means the _variable_ named `AVMetadataCommonKeyLocation` is a string, it does not say anything about what kind of content the item should be providing when using that key. You are supposed to use this _variable_ with the `key` property of `AV(Mutable)MedatdataItem` which is a string.